How best to minimize shoot through with push-pull mosfet driver
I am building a custom made portable chisel sharpener from scratch. (Sick of manual sharpening! Can't find a good one!)
The plan is to use an 18v battery as power source, and it will see a lot of use - so I want it to run as efficiently as possible. I am avoiding the use of BJT's for this reason.

Can I drive an IRF840 using the 44E as a high side switch (integrated emitter-follower) to saturate a 2n7000? (IE. connect 44E Gnd. to 2N7000 gate?)

Or should I use a BS250P as high side switch for the IRF840 gate, 2N7000 to "empty" the 840 gate, and the 44E to trigger both BS250P/2N7000 gates high/low simultaneously? (As image describes)


I realize I will get shoot through losses if I use both P-FET and N-FET together (44E rise/fall=both 200μs) however - high side driving is less efficient (iinm) and I am not actually sure I can SOURCE current with A3144E in order to use just one FET to drive the larger one.
What would constitute the simplest and most effective way to attain a low duty cycle, thus efficient operation using the mentioned components?

I am fairly new to all this and self taught; any helpful replies are kindly appreciated.

What makes you think that using MOSFETs instead of BJTs avoids shoot-through? You still get shoot-through in the circuit you've drawn every time it switches.

There are some issues here: 1. the P-ch is shown always conducting; it's a diode. 2. The battery isn't grounded. 3. PNP/NPN are bipolar transistors, P-ch/N-ch are MOSFETs; the text mixes both freely, yet the schematic shows MOSFET symbols and part numbers. 4. 44E isn't defined (are you abbreviating A3144E?). 5. A3144E appears to be a hall-effect (magnetic activated) switch; how will it be generating a PWM signal?

What is the goal? Turn on the MOSFET when the hall effect sensor detects the chisel to be sharpened?

-By PNP/NPN I meant N-FET/P-FET. (rectified)
I know BJTs will shoot through same as FETs. MOSFETs are generally more efficient aren't they? once charged, it'll conduct, not requiring continuous current flow making it "better", no?


Battery isn't grounded because that's a switch, however crude it may be ! lol
2N7000 will prevent wasted current once 840 is charged, right ? the gate is isolated so once charged to 60pf it'll stay charged until emptied (correct me if mistaken pls)


The goal is to use the 44E to close the 840 and repel the stator, repeat. not much torque required here,



You only need to drive the MOSFET gate hard with a push pull driver if you want to switch fast in order to use PWM to control your motor speed. Otherwise if it's just for on/off you can drive it with one transistor and a pullup or pulldown resistor, which solves your shoot through problem. I think Tim believes you're going to use PWM because you're using a push pull driver. So what do you actually want?

I want the device to be "self triggered" and start up with a push. once spinning it won't provide much torque but this is intentional, it's not needed in this application so I want to see how efficiently I can make it run.

44E=A3144E, apologies for the confusion - also for the jumbled reply, not familiar with this sites format.

https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/90853/ALLEGRO/A3144EUA.html

If you want to turn on the MOSFET when the hall sensor triggers, you can do that:

When the sensor triggers, it pulls down the output, which turns on the small signal P-MOSFET (X1) which turns on the power N-MOSFET. Otherwise R2 pulls the gate low so it turns off.
Note IRF840 has rather high RdsON of 0.85 ohms. If your motor uses more than one amp it will heat a lot and need a heat sink. I'd recommend picking a MOSFET with much lower RdsON. Use \$ P=R_{DSON} I^2 \$ and pick RdsON to keep P below 1W.

Now if you want your motor to start when the hall sensor triggers, then keep running for a while while the sensor does not trigger, it's a bit more complicated.
You can use a monostable, preferably with a negative trigger input, which suits the Hall sensor's active-low output, and a positive output, so it can drive your N-MOSFET directly with a gate resistor.
So if your Hall sensor detects a magnet on the spinning wheel, and you set your monostable to stay on for a bit longer than the time it takes to do one full rotation, then if you start it manually the monostable will retrigger on each turn and keep it running. Then if you stop it with your hand for longer than the monostable delay, it will not retrigger and just turn off.

Thankyou bobflux - I was under the impression that using both a high side and a low side FET together would decrease overall current consumption and make better use of the sensors qualities; I will use just the P-FET as described.
One more question: would it be possible to use the A3144E as an "active high" signal if installed with gnd/output reversed?
The datasheet mentions that it includes an "emitter follower" does this mean its action is reversible, and I can use it directly with a small signal FET, negating the need for an IC or monostable?

No if you reverse polarity on the sensor as you suggest it will most likely let the smoke out. Note the schematic I put in the answer will only turn on the MOSFET when the sensor is active, so it's fine if the sensor detects the chisel to be sharpened but it won't work if the magnet is on the wheel, because it will turn off as soon as the sensor is no longer in front of the magnet. So for the hand start you talk about in the comments, you'll have to give more details... like rpm and motor current for example.

Thanks - that helps clear things up I think. What does the "emitter follower" actually do if not enable a positive current to be driven?
The sensor is meant to detect the rotor magnets and pulse the inductor when sensor is triggered, driving the rotor around and out of the sensor vicinity and so the next rotor magnet can be attracted to the iron core and be repelled, etc.
No idea what the RPM will be, planning to adjust the voltage after the fact to tune it to RPM needed.
The chisel will not influence the sensor itself but be sharpened by the spinning rotor with 400grit affixed.

I don't see "emitter follower" in the datasheet, it's an open collector output. OK so you're making a DIY brushless motor, that makes sense. It should work.

Yeah - I should have made my ambition clearer.
Also - I must have gotten it confused with a different sensor because you're right, A3144E is open collector  (no emitter follower) Thankyou for the open source assist with this, much appreciated.   :)

You're welcome, i hope it works out!
